# Unobstructed deformations of Hamiltonian manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

It is well known that compact complex manifolds with $H^2(X,T_X)=0$ and compact Kähler manifolds with trivial canonical bundle have unobstructed deformations, but besides them, are there other examples of complex manifolds with unobstructed deformations? I find Hamiltonian manifolds may have the possibility of satisfying this condition which is decribed in Bogomolov's and Tian's paper. In Tian's paper 《[Smoothness of the universal deformation space of compact Calabi-Yau manifolds and its Peterson-Weil metric](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812798411_0029)》 page 636, there is a statement that:

> If $X$ is a compact Hamiltonian manifold. We can define an isomorphism between $\Gamma(X,\Omega^{0,q}(T_X))$ and $\Gamma(X,\Omega^{1,q})$ by the nondegenerate holomorphic $(2,0)$-form defining the Hamiltonian structure over $X$. One can prove that the local universal deformation space of $X$ is isomorphic to $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb C)$ by repeating the above arguments except that we use the fact that $\partial H^{0,2}(X,\mathbb C)=0$ instead of Hodge theory for Kähler manifold. Thus, one can drop the Kähler condition in this case.

And my question is:

1. a nondegenerate holomorphic $(2,0)$ form defines an isomorphism between $\Gamma(X,\Omega^{0,q}(T_X))$ and $\Gamma(X,\Omega^{1,q})$, does arbitrary nondegenerate holomorphic $(p,0)$ form defines an isomorphism between $\Gamma(X,\Omega^{0,q}(T_X))$ and $\Gamma(X,\Omega^{p-1,q})$?
2. since for a ($n,0$) form $\Omega$, $\partial\Omega$ is always $0$, thus by Cartan formula $i_{[X,Y]}=[L_X,i_Y]$ and choose $\partial$ closed $\omega_1,\omega_2$ we can get $[\omega_1,\omega_2]\lrcorner \Omega=\partial(\omega_1\lrcorner\omega_2\lrcorner\Omega)$, then by $\partial \bar\partial$ lemma, we get $[\omega_1,\omega_2]$ being $\bar\partial$ exact. But for a $(2,0)$ form, we don't have $\partial\Omega=0$, so we can't use the same method to get $[\omega_1,\omega_2]$ being $\bar\partial$ exact. Is there a gap in Tian's paper to prove the unobstructedness of deformation or did I missed something?

By the way I don't see what he means and why $\partial H^{0,2}(X,\mathbb C)=0$, does anybody has a clue?
Any comment is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Regarding your first question, what do you mean by a nondegenerate $p$-form for $p > 2$? Note that the vector bundles $\Omega^{0,q}(TX)$ and $\Omega^{p-1,q}$ have different dimensions for $p\neq \{2,\dim X\}$, so there can't be no such isomorphism. A variant has been studied in the paper Higher Symplectic Geometry by Christopher Rogers https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4068 (albeit in the smooth and not holomorphic context).

Comment: That remark in Tian's paper is known to be incorrect. See Theorem 1.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.05258.pdf for a weaker statement, which seems to contain all that can be saved from Tian's remark (plus of course extra work by the authors)

Comment: By the way, nowadays the terminology "holomorphic symplectic" is standard, while "Hamiltonian" is obsolete (in this context)